# MemoryError using MLPClassifier from sklearn.neural_network

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm running python 3.5 on a windows 10 64-bit operating system.

When I try to implement `MLPClassifier` the code runs for a while and then gives me a `MemoryError`.

I think it's due to the size of the hidden layer that I'm asking it to run but I need to  run this size to collect my data. How can I circumvent this error?

**Code**

```
gamma=[1,10,100,1000,10000,100000]#create array for range of gamma values
score_train=[]
score_test=[]
for j in gamma:
    mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', random_state=0, hidden_layer_sizes=[j,j], activation='tanh').fit(data_train, classes_train)
    score_train.append(mlp.score(data_train,classes_train))
    score_test.append(mlp.score(data_test,classes_test))
print (score_train)
print (score_test)
```

**Error**

[Memory Erroy Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r132e.png)

Answer (score 1):

> the code runs for a while and then gives me a MemoryError. I think it's due to the size of the hidden layer that I'm asking it to run but I need to run this size to collect my data.

Yes, it's the size of the hidden-layers! And the remaining part of that sentence does not make much sense (continue reading)!

Please make sure to read read the [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html#neural-networks-supervised) and [API-docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html)

#### Now some more specific remarks:

- The sizes of the hidden-layer does not have anything to do with the collection of your data!

  - input- and output-layers will be build based on the sizes of your `X,y`!
  - `hidden_layer_sizes=[j,j]` is actually creating **2** hidden-layers!
- In the MLP, all layers are **fully connected!**

  - a call with `hidden_layer_sizes=[100000, 100000]` as you try to do will use **~76 gigabytes of memory** (assuming 64-bit doubles) just for these weights connecting these 2 layers alone!

    - and this is just one connection-layer: input-h0 and h1-output are still missing
- `lbfgs` is a completely different solver than all the others. Don't use it without some understanding of the implications! **It's not default!**

  - It's a **full-batch method** and therefore uses a lot more memory when sample-size is big!
  - Additionally, there are more internal reasons to use more memory compared to the other (first-order-) methods
  - Not that precise, but the docs already gave some hints: `Note: The default solver ‘adam’ works pretty well on relatively large datasets (with thousands of training samples or more) in terms of both training time and validation score. For small datasets, however, ‘lbfgs’ can converge faster and perform better.`

Comment: Yes that helps clarify a lot! I checked back through the earlier questions and realised there was a much easier method for me to obtain the performance score. Reading through the instructions again did help pinpoint what I needed to change so thank you!

Comment: Hi sascha how did you calculate the memory usage for the hidden layers?